# Refresh Core Data in ViewController when Modal View (2nd view) is Dismissed - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to figure out how to reload my UIViewController after I dismiss a Modal View. What's happening is I segue from View 1 (my UIVIewController) to a Modal View where I make an update to Core Data. Upon completion, I save the Core Data and dismiss the Modal View, sending the user back to View 1 (the UIViewController). Problem is the UIViewController is not pulling the updated change to the Core Data (but instead is presenting the old information, because it has not been refreshed).

This was the closest answer I think that could work, but I'm having trouble translating from Objective-C to Swift.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Use NSFetchedResultsController to manage core data updates, or if you are using NSFetchRequest to fetch CoreData entities, after you dismiss modal view do FetchRequest again and update you ViewController with new data.

Comment: I tried using the NSFetchedResultsController, but can that be used on UIViewControllers? I know they work with UITableViews great. Also, I understand I need to pull again/update the ViewController, that's what I'm having trouble with (I don't know how to do it).

Comment: sure you can use in UIViewController, se my post below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion for this issue is to create delegate that will notify View 1.

For instance:

in presented view controller create delegate:

```
protocol NotifyReloadCoreData
    func notifyDelegate()
end
```

create property of view controller:

```
var delegate: NotifyReloadCoreData?
```

when press save or something like that :

```
delegate.notifyDelegate()
```

in your View 1

```
class UIViewController1: UIViewController, NotifyReloadCoreData
```

and implement function

```
func notifyDelegate(){
    // reload core data here
}
```

Comment: To be clear to anyone in the future, I effectively solved my problem with a combination of the two solutions from NickCatib and Roman Simenok. I created an NSFetchedResultsController roughly similar to that described by Roman, but then I created the delegate to push a variable from my modal view back to my first veiwcontroller. I then used the viewDidAppear function to call the NSFetchedResultsController to make sure it would re-query the Core Data, based on a predicate that was driven using a variable pushed from the delegate. Clear as mud. But big thanks to both Nick and Roman.

Answer (score 4):

Here is quick NSFetchedResultsController example

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

            do {
                try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
            } catch {
                print("An error occurred")
            }
    }

private lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {
        let animalsFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Animal")
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "classification.order", ascending: true)
        animalsFetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(
            fetchRequest: animalsFetchRequest,
            managedObjectContext: self.context,
            sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
            cacheName: nil)

        frc.delegate = self

        return frc
}()

// delegate method

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
            // update UI
}
```

Comment: Novice question here, but how do I pull a property from it? I.e., with NSFetchedResults I just executeFetchResults and save that to a NSManagedObject (from which I can simply do something like NSManagedObject.propertyCode to get the value. Is there something similar I'd do to pull a property from the fetchResultController?

Comment: @skind `self.fetchResultController.fetchedObject` is the same array as you get when you `executeFetchRequest` but method `controllerDidChangeContent` say you when CoreData updated and `self.fetchResultController.fetchedObject` will have new object with all you changes.

Comment: This is a rather large ask, but do you have the above in Swift (language I'm working in)?

Comment: @skind here what i found in google so far, try it :) and don't forget to up vote if it's useful

Comment: I just updated my code. My code was slightly modified, but this gets to the gist of it. For some reason the view is still not updating. Under the controllerDidChangeContent function, do I need to call data again from CoreData in order to update my UI? I tried that but it doesn't seem to update anything on my ViewController.

Comment: @skind Does fetchResultController call `controllerDidChangeContent`? If not make sure that you changes saved to CoreData, after you change some entity call `managedContext.save()` after save `controllerDidChangeContent` should be executed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107752/discussion-between-roman-simenok-and-skind).